# The value of input range is not updated on submit

Tags: jsf, updates, rangeslider, passthrough-elements

I have some rangesliders like:

```
<h:form>    
        <input name="range1" id="range1" min="0" max="5" value="#{prefProfileBean.pref1}" type="range"/>
        <input name="range2" id="range2" min="0" max="5" value="#{prefProfileBean.pref2}" type="range" />
...

<p:commandButton value="Profil speichern" onclick="PF('updprofile').show();" action="#{prefProfileBean.submit}" />
```

in View the value of the sliders is updated, but as i press submit button the values are not written, instead the values stay the same as they was initially. that way i cant change and save the values in database.

can i use the onchange action somehow to override the initial values with the shown changed ones...

can someone tell me how to get the actual chosen value out of this components?

Comment: HTML 5 (`type="range"`).

Comment: Try the [slider](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/slider.xhtml) component. I don't think plain HTML tags handle bindings.

Comment: Look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/TagDecorator.html

Comment: @Diego, your comment made me think of this [blog post](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3035). I don't know how it works, and I've never tried it, but the author sets `jsf:value="#{userView.user.firstname}"` on an `input` element. I don't think it will help OP, just thought you'd be interested.

Comment: @Diego: not in this way, but with html5 friendly markup they do

Comment: @DavidS interesting, I'm still working with an old JSF version and never seen this way of writing views :)

Comment: @diego: it has only advantages if you want to combine jsf with javascript ui frameworks

Comment: You need JSF-2.2, with which you can blend HTML5 markup with JSF value bindings. Without that you'll have to do more than a little more work to save the bindings